# Expiration policy for the StoreClient (Python)

Tags: zapier

Running a python script with Zapier is quite easy, in combination with `requests` and `StoreClient` it's possible to understand how to hack some datasources. The question is, the doc mention its [limitations](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#limitations), but does not mention which is the policy for the `StoreClient` to self-expire, I assume by default cached data will never expire. It's that assumption asserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct - keys will expire if you do not touch them in 3 months. I just made sure the documentation reflects that clearly!